# the prediction results are so far from the original data that the new information cannot be used, is there something wrong?

Tags: deep-learning, normalization, forecasting, bilstm, pytorch-forecasting

if anyone can help I would be very grateful, I use a hybrid method to forecast, the deep learning architecture I use is Bi-LSTM, my data is 2788 data with 2 predictor variables, I use data normalization using a min-max scaler.  is it correct?, I have doubts about the nominal distance of the data, namely in this case I used gold and silver prices that were too far away, when making predictions, the forecast results were very far from the original data, did I do something wrong, if anyone knows, please help  , Thank You

I have tried modifying the Bi-LSTM model by adding a hidden layer but it doesn't give good results, I want forecasting results that can have forecasting data that fits the original data

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.